# Antisamy-tinymce removing <img> tag

Tags: html, tinymce, antisamy

I am passing a image which is having html below :-

```
<p>tag img src="http://some image url link" alt="N2QWv.png (512&times;512)" /></p>
```

and my  tag is getting removed though I have not provided it in remove tag.

I don't want my  tag to be removed. Please any one who can help with this

Answer (score 1):

Give below in your policy file :-

```
<tag name="img" action="validate">
    <attribute name="src" /> 
    <attribute name="style" />
    <attribute name="title" />
    <attribute name="alt" />
</tag>

<attribute name="alt" description="The 'alt' attribute provides alternative text to users when its visual representation is not available">
    <regexp-list>
        <regexp name="paragraph" />
    </regexp-list>
</attribute>
```

In global attribute tag add this :-

```
<attribute name="src" />
```